# Black hole distortion shader in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I found shader code that has the effect of warping a space around a certain point. It's a cool effect, but it's missing some animation, so I've added something to it:

```
Shader "Marek/BlackHoleDistortion"
{
    Properties {
        _DistortionStrength ("Distortion Strength", Range(0, 10)) = 0
        _Timer("Timer", Range(0, 10)) = 0
        _HoleSize ("Hole Size", Range(0, 1)) = 0.1736101
        _HoleEdgeSmoothness ("Hole Edge Smoothness", Range(1, 4)) = 4
        _ObjectEdgeArtifactFix ("Object Edge Artifact Fix", Range(1, 10)) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }
        GrabPass{ }
        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
            }
            ZWrite Off

            CGPROGRAM
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles 
            #pragma target 3.0
            uniform sampler2D _GrabTexture;
            uniform float _DistortionStrength;
            uniform float _HoleSize;
            uniform float _HoleEdgeSmoothness;
            uniform float _ObjectEdgeArtifactFix;
            uniform float _Timer;

            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
            };

            struct VertexOutput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 projPos : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                o.posWorld = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.projPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);

                COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.projPos.z);

                return o;
            }

            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);

                float3 viewDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - i.posWorld.xyz);
                float3 normalDirection = i.normalDir;
                float2 sceneUVs = (i.projPos.xy / i.projPos.w);
                float node_9892 = (_HoleSize * -1.0 + 1.0);
                float node_3969 = (1.0 - pow(1.0 - max(0, dot(normalDirection, viewDirection)), clamp(_DistortionStrength - _Timer, 0, _DistortionStrength)));
                float node_9136 = (length(float2(ddx(node_3969), ddy(node_3969))) * _HoleEdgeSmoothness);
                float node_4918 = pow(node_3969, 6.0);
                float node_1920 = (1.0 - smoothstep((node_9892 - node_9136), (node_9892 + node_9136), node_4918));
                float3 finalColor = (
                    lerp(
                        float4(node_1920, node_1920, node_1920, node_1920), 
                        float4(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                        pow(
                            pow(1.0 - max(0, dot(normalDirection, viewDirection)), 1.0), 
                            _ObjectEdgeArtifactFix
                        )
                    ) * tex2D(_GrabTexture, ((node_4918 * (sceneUVs.rg * _Time * -2.0 + 1.0)) + sceneUVs.rg)).rgb).rgb;

                return fixed4(finalColor, 1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }

    FallBack "Diffuse"

}
```

Now, the problem is that in order to make the distortion disappear after certain time, I need to include some variable into the equation - here I'm calling it `_Timer`. I'm not using the `_Time` built in because of obvious reasons - it's an ever growing value and I need something that starts from 0 each time the object using this shader is made active. C# code handling passing that parameter looks as follows:

```
public void Update() {
    _timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

    _renderer.material.SetFloat("_Timer", _timeElapsed);
}
```

The question is - can I do it better? I would like this shader's code to be more of a self-contained thing - without the need to pass parameters from cs script to it.

Comment: you can [_Time](https://answers.unity.com/questions/266584/shaders-why-is-time-stored-in-a-vector4.html) in your shader.so instead of using `_Timer` in your shader use `_Time.y`.Your way is not wrong because sometimes we need to use script to Initialize variables in shader

Comment: Actually when using `_Time.y` no effect is visible.

Comment: you can't see effect in Edit mode , play the game

Comment: I meant that I can't see the effect in play mode as well :)

Comment: And this `_Time.y` variable holds the actual value of time, so it will not work in my case - I need something that is 0 at the time the game object shader is attached to is activated. So like an auto resetting value - when the shader is doing it's thing on an active object value of the variable should grow, then it's deactivated and activated again and it again starts from 0.

Comment: Hmm if it didn't work , try It by the code.you can declare a integer (0,1) in shader as boolean then use [OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) to reseting values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do it better?

In-short, yes and no. If you want the shader to behave differently per `material` you simply cannot avoid passing a property from C#. You can however avoid doing this in `Update` by passing a `start` time and computing the `elapse` time in the shader.

**C#**

```
void OnEnable ()
{
    _renderer.material.SetFloat("_StartTime", Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
}
```

**Shader**

```
uniform float _StartTime;

float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR
{
   float elapse = _Time.y - _StartTime;
}
```

Now, although this will tie directly into the setup you are currently using, it should be noted that accessing the `.material` property will clone the material (which can break batching, among other things). 
This can be avoided with the more recent introduction of [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)s.

Comment: This looks promising, but can I ask for a slightly bigger example? I'm not sure how to use this Kernel method in my shader code.

Comment: My apologies. The Kernel is just your fragment program. I'll update my post for clarity.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. So f*ckin' simple :D . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Unity provides a handful of built-in values for your shaders: things like current object’s transformation matrices, time etc.
>
> You just use them in ShaderLab like you’d use any other property, the only difference is that you don’t have to declare it somewhere - they are “built in”.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/455/Documentation/Manual/SL-BuiltinValues.html

there is a clever way of giving you 4 variations of the value, potentially saving you a multiply operation by re-using the pre-multiplied value for every pixel being rendered. There are 4 values available.

[image]

```
 _Time.x = time / 20
 _Time.y = time
 _Time.z = time * 2
 _Time.w = time * 3
```

this is a simple example that show you how it works:

[image: Circle]

```
Shader "Example/Circle"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off 

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }



            float circle(in float2 _st, in float _radius){
                float2 dist = distance(_st,float2(0.5,0.5));
                float result = step(dist,_radius);
                return result;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
            float WaveTime = sin(_Time.z);
            float3 color = float3(1,1,1)*circle(i.uv,WaveTime);

            return float4( color, 1.0 );
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

In comments you mentioned that you want reset time value when you enable it , so here you need to Initialize Time value with script.

so you should use your own Time In shader:

```
Properties
{
    _Timer("Timer",Float) = 0
}

float WaveTime = sin(_Timer);
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Circle : MonoBehaviour {
    public float _timeElapsed;


    void OnEnable(){
        _timeElapsed = 0;
    }

public void Update() {
    _timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    var _renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    _renderer.material.SetFloat("_Timer", _timeElapsed);
}
}
```